# ASP.NET Different Session Variable Value on the Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session-variables

I have been trying to solve this problem for 2 days now and I haven't been able to find anything useful on the net yet. Strange thing is, this used to work..! After changing some settings on the web server (unfortunately I don't recall exact changes) It ceased to work :(

Here is what happens;

I have a hidden field on an aspx page whose value gets set to the current datetime string(long datetime sting, seconds included) on page_load (aspx.cs, codebehind). At the same time, this random value is recorded in a session variable right on the next line in the same method.

Than (to explain briefly) I send this value to a web service where I check this value against the value stored in the session variable. Guess what..there are not the same! This used to work but not anymore and I don't know what changed or went wrong. Since the value of this string is datetime value (with seconds), I can see that this value is changing by 2 seconds "Most of The Time". When I debug the code on the IIS (by attaching the worker process) I can see that the value recovered from the session is 2 seconds later from the value recovered from the hidden field.

This is working on my development machine, problem is, it is not working on the web server (Windows server 2008 r2)

I know there are alternatives you can propose, I myself can think of alternatives to this approach too, but I am really very much interested in solving the puzzle here...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

edit: simple approach

**method call on the page_load**

```
addSecureString(System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
```

**method that records the vaiables**

```
protected void addSecureString(string s) {

        string secureS = "111" + s;
        Session.Add("securestring", secureS);
        hdnss.Value = Session["securestring"].ToString();

}
```

**on the web service**

```
string tocheck = Session["securestring"];
```

hdnss -> id of the hidden field on the page
Note: I am taking the Seconds value of the datetime since that is the part that matters and changing..

Comment: Are you setting both values to `System.DateTime.Now()` or are you setting a separate variable to `System.DateTime.Now()` and then assigning both values to that? It might be that simple.

Comment: :) a separate string variable gets the datetime value at 1 point, then both hidden field and session variable are assigned to this string value

Comment: It was worth a try :). Are the web site and the web service in the same application? How is the web service reading the value from the session variable in the web site?

Comment: Rather than explaining your code, it is often more useful to post an example of it (simplified, of course) so it is easier to understand the exact approach you are taking.

Comment: @shai yes it was:)  They are in the same application yes. How service reads session variables? Easy -> [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

Comment: If it is not already, try wrapping the code in `Page_Load` in a `if(!this.IsPostBack)` block. You might be resetting it on each page load before/when calling the WebService

Comment: @shai There is no postback happening on the page. Everything is done with ajax techniques. But I have already done what u have proposed, just in case. No luck there ...

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

There are special considerations when having your web service interact with session: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx

Comment: I have checked the article. There is no problem on my part with respect to the considerations mentioned there. But thanks :)